# How to handle Google Calendar API push notifications?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I can't seem to make sense of [this article](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en#renewing-notification-channels).

I'm trying to create 2-way syncing of events between my web app and Google Calendar. I've got my events successfully syncing to Google Calendar, but the push notifications Google sends me aren't of any use.

When I create a new event, and then I create a watch:

```
$channel = new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel();
$channel->setId($watchId);
$channel->setType('web_hook');
$channel->setAddress(URL::route('gapi.watchEvent'));
$channel->setResourceId($seg->gapi_event_id); // does this do anything??
$channel->setToken(json_encode(['segment_id'=>$seg->id]));
$channel->setParams([
    'ttl' => 2628000, // is this respected??
]);

$watchResp = $calendarService->events->watch($googleCalendarId, $channel);
```

Firstly, does `$channel->setResourceId` do anything? I want to listen to changes to a specific event, but always seems to give me notifications for the entire calendar.

The headers that Google sends me look like this:

```
"X-Goog-Channel-Id": "qJSdaxkKKkXXXXXXXXXX",
"X-Goog-Channel-Expiration": "Thu, 10 Sep 2015 01:45:57 GMT",
"X-Goog-Resource-State": "exists",
"X-Goog-Message-Number": "1811101",
"X-Goog-Resource-Id": "wBkuOkYwEhDiXXXXXXXXX",
"X-Goog-Resource-Uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/9t4rmmb2rfdvcXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json",
```

The `X-Goog-Channel-Id` is the watch id that I chose. `X-Goog-Resource-Uri` appears to just be a link to the calendar. And I don't know what `X-Goog-Resource-Id`. It doesn't appear to be either my calendar ID or my event ID.

All I want to know is what data changed? How do I extract that information out of the push notification?

I don't care if I have to subscribe to every event my app creates, or just once per calendar.

Comment: When you create a watch request, id": string, should be channel Id. Once the request is successful, response includes the resource id of the resource. For example, if you want to want events, you should send watch request to events.watchhttps://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch

Comment: X-Goog-Resource-Id is the resource id of your resource and is unique. Its the number given to your resource. If you are watching events, then any change to the events on your calendar, you will get notification. check the Receiving notifications section in the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push. Then you can do events.list to check the change.

Comment: That's quite vague. It turns out the "resource ID" is that of the the "watch". It's not the Watch ID I generated (aka Channel ID), nor the Calendar ID, nor the Event ID -- it's Google's internal watch identifier.

Comment: Any idea what I'm doing wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654504/calendar-events-notification-not-received-on-server

Answer (score 26):

When you get a push notification, it contains almost no useful information. You have to make a request back to Google to ask what's changed since your last sync. Read [this article](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) for more information.

Basically, you want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID']` (the watch ID *you* generated) and/or `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID']` (the watch ID Google generates) to look up the calendar ID that you created a watch on in your own DB (you'll have to store this when you create the watch).

Once you have the calendar ID, you have to do an [events/list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) request to find out what's changed. They have a PHP example on that page, but you'll have to add in the `syncToken` which you should also store.

Despite [events/watch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) being under "events", you're *really* listening to *all* the events for a calendar, not changes in a specific event (don't be fooled by the PHP API which has a `Google_Service_Calendar_Channel::setResourceId` option -- it does nothing). Make sure to store the `resourceId` you get back. You'll need that to [stop](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#stopping-notifications) notifications.

Also, watches expire after some amount of time. And you [can't refresh them](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels) either. I suggest you stop the old watch a week or two before its about to expire and create a new one. The new one must have a different ID than the old one.

Comment: It took me forever to realize that you get the `syncToken` by making an events/list request. Might want to make apparent in your answer because it seemed to me you were getting your syncToken out of thin air.

Comment: @ChinotoVokro I still dont get it , if you get the sync token from the evets/list then how you get the list of the events that were changed, docs say we need to provide it with the request to list only those that were changed.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam It's been forever since I had to implement this, but I believe how this works is that you make a request without a syncToken, store the nextSyncToken from the response somewhere, and then when you get a push notification, make a event/list request with the syncToken you stored from before. When you get a response from event/list, make sure to overwrite your stored syncToken with the response's nextSyncToken, otherwise the response will contain old data along with the new.

Comment: @ChinotoVokro yeah i figured it out that first time user passes the oauth consent screen and logins we request for all the events and there we have the first sync token , we save it against the channel in our db and then every time a channel posts on the webhook via watch we send request to get all events with synctoken and the results will have only changed events. One more important thing is that whenever we find changed events we need to get the nextsynctoken and update the one in db

Comment: This seems insane to me. Would it have been that hard to include the modified event in the notification? This way you have to retrieve the sync token, call the sync endpoint, maybe multiple times if the results are paginated, then save the new token... and what if another notification arrives during that time? So you have to deal with concurrency issues, even if the notifications are for completely different events. Now I understand why ToDoist's Calendar integration is so buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years and quite erratically Google changes the header key it sends... I've had :

```
x-goog-channel-id
X-Goog-Channel-ID
X-Goog-Channel-Id
```

This was very frustrating to solve, so you either edit the header to lower case it or create an alert/log when one of the expected header's key is not found.