# Google Calendar Watch and Events working together

Tags: events, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I am creating a Node/Express Webapp that would mirror a user's calendar. It would get a notification for every change in the users calendar, and would update the DB with the latest of that user's calendar.

Lets assume that we want to monitor john.doe@gmail.com. Kindly tell me if this is the best (and only) way to do it:

1. Set up for [Push notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) - While doing so, we provide (amongst other fields):

   - **token** - A plain-text that would be echoed back. *This is where I can put something like 'calOwner=john.doe@gmail.com'*
   - **id** - A UUID channel id
2. Upon every change, my webhook will get a push notification that would contain:

   - **token** : calOwner=john.doe@gmail.com
   - **id** : the channelId - *I dont understand if this field alone can be used to trace this notification message back to john.doe@gmail.com*
3. Now that I know john.doe@gmail.com has changed, I would do a [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) with a [synchToken](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync). This will return me the change in john's calendar since last synch

What baffles me here is that the seemingly important fields **channelId** and **resourceId** (which appears as **x-goog-resource-id** in the push notification header) are useless, and the only field that ties the [push](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) message to [list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) is an *optional plain-text* field **token** .

Kindly tell me if this is the only way to track a user's calendar.

**UPDATE**

Thanks @KENdi for the answer.

My struggle was with the point that simply looking at a push notification message, there is no way to trace it back to john.doe@gmail.com . I now understand why such is the case, that a push notification does not contain the calendarId, but the resourceId instead (which, in plain terms is the event object). It is so because an event can be associated with multiple calendars, and hence multiple calendarIds. Hence, it is the subscriber's responsibility to maintain association of the channel to the calendarId that he had used to create the channel at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, you need the calendar [push notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), to notify you about all the changes happened in the Google Calendar.

The purpose of [`X-Goog-Resource-ID`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#understanding-the-notification-message-format) is an opaque value that identifies the watched resource. And this ID is stable across API versions.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932239/how-to-handle-google-calendar-api-push-notifications) to know more about the purpose of `X-Goog-Resource-Id`.