# How to track changes of calendars in the user's calendar list?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, webhooks, watch

I opened a push notification channel for the `CalendarList`. Google notifies my app about adding/removing/hiding items on the list, but not about changes to the items themselves.

[Push notifications docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) mention that only `Acl`, `CalendarList`, `Events`, and `Settings` can be watched. I tried to register `CalendarList` list channel providing id of a particular calendar, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Is it possible to watch for changes of other properties of the calendars, like summary?**

It appears to me, that an alternative would be to perform a periodical synchronization of all registered accounts. But then how can I ensure that users see calendars with the latest changes whenever they need them? I could trigger a background sync every time calendars are displayed, maybe with some throttling. However this doesn't look like a very good solution.

**Is there any other way to keep locally stored calendars up-to-date?**

Comment: You can check [this post from the G Suite Administrator support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6110475?hl=en) about to track the calendar notifications and changes in the user's calendars, events and subscriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to watch changes of properties of the calendars. And Google calendar is not really consistent with change notifications. Notifications might come after several minutes.

I keep copies of events and whenever there is an update, I look at the difference between copy event in my database and incoming update and decide if users need to see this update. To keep locally stored calendars up-to-date, I open push notification channel for calendars and also periodically check -because of inconsistency- to see if anything has changed.

You can also check my answer about periodical synchronization in [Get event info from resource id on push notification google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798989/get-event-info-from-resource-id-on-push-notification-google-calendar/43801130#43801130).

Comment: That's how I dealt with it. Some changes won't even be included in the incremental sync, so I do a full sync periodically, compare with local copies and update changes.