# Find Updated events from Google Watch Push Notification Response

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I have created a watch Channel on my calender and I am successfully receiving all updates from Google PUSH Notifcation.
But I am not able to use that response to get craeted/updated events.
I read few docs and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932239/how-to-handle-google-calendar-api-push-notifications) questions that I need to use `X-Goog-Resource-ID` from the response and hit events list API.

But value of this `X-Goog-Resource-ID` is neither a calender id and neither it is a event id so how can I use this in events list API ?

I am using Python and Service Account for the integration.

Documentaion :

- https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/calendar_v3.events.html#list
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#making-watch-requests

Response from PUSH :

```
   "X-Goog-Channel-Expiration": "",
    "X-Goog-Channel-ID": "",
    "X-Goog-Channel-Token": "",
    "X-Goog-Message-Number": "",
    "X-Goog-Resource-ID": <resource id>,
    "X-Goog-Resource-State": "exists",
    "X-Goog-Resource-URI": <calender UI>
```

Google Functions I tried using :

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

service.calendars().get(calendarId=X-Goog-Resource-ID).execute()

service.events().list(calendarId=calenderId', eventId=X-Goog-Resource-ID).execute()
```

Is their any ref Python Example of using digesting Calender PUSH Notification or which API/Function I need to call with what oaarms to get the created/updated events ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X-Goog-Resource-ID` header holds a value that identifies that particular resource across the APIs. The whole push notifications basically informs you that something has changed on that calendar.

Now if you want to know exactly what changed, I strongly advise you to perform a [synchronisation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync). One way to do this is to perform a full synchronisation and store the `nextSyncToken`. Then, when you receive a push notification telling you about a change in the calendar, you only have to use the `syncToken` to know what has changed since your last synchronisation. You can see a working full example on the linked docs.

## UPDATE

If you are watching multiple calendars through push notifications, you will need a system in place to track which calendar is being modified at a time. The `X-Goog-Resource-ID` header maps with the Calendar ID, and it can be used along `syncToken` to run a [`events.list()`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) request to receive the updated events.

Comment: Thanks, yes I figured that out.

 -  resourceId returned in Watch Request, is mapped with the CalenderId . Now whenever you will receive any PUSH from watch in the POST you will receive resourceId in the header. From that Header resource id  you can find out which Calender is getting updated (if you match Header value with Watch Response Resource Id) and hit events.list() API to get Updated events.  
- So for every Watch  created Ioneneeds to save the Response so that from PUSH Header they can figure out which calender is getting updated.

Hope It makes sense.

Comment: If my above comment is right then Can you please Edit your answer to accommodate this . Since I was supposed to manage the multiple calendars and I had to save the Watch Response. For one calender you can ignore the Resposne since you already know  for which calender you need to call the `events.list` API.

Comment: Hi there @user5594493! Thanks for clarifying the question, I have just updated my answer. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I am receiving more than one PUSH for a single event create/change. Is this Normal?  Also isn't there will be unnecessary processing to get the changes from more than first PUSH for the same event change? On the first PUSH, changes are digested so on the Second PUSH why to calculate same changes again ? Is there any way to ignore multiple PUSH of same changes?

Comment: This seems insane to me. Would it have been that hard to include the modified event in the notification? This way you have to retrieve the sync token, call the sync endpoint, maybe multiple times if the results are paginated, then save the new token... and what if another notification arrives during that time? So you have to deal with concurrency issues, even if the notifications are for completely different events. Now I understand why ToDoist's Calendar integration is so buggy.