# Google Drive api feedbackNotifications

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

the current situation is that you are receiving a notification when a file is added, changed or deleted in a specific drive folder. However, the value of the header value X-Goog-Resource-State, which is sent when notifying whenever it is added, changed, or deleted, is always changed. In the document, there are values ​​depending on the situation, such as add, remove, update, trash. If anyone knows why the value only changes no matter what action you take, please reply. Thank you in advance.

reference link : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push?hl=english

I expected header value remove in notification when resource is deleted, but X-Goog-Resource-State: change
this value came

Comment: refer this [find-updated-events-from-google-watch-push-notification-respon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672431/find-updated-events-from-google-watch-push-notification-response)